# Generalized Derivative is a Unique Linear Map.

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

I need to prove the following : Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R^m} \to \mathbb{R^n}$, then  derivative is a unique.

Here is my proof:

Assume that two such linear maps exist say $A,B$ from $\mathbb{R^m} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ by definition of differentiability

For any $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta_1, \delta_2 >0$ such that

$\left|F(a+h)- F(a) - Ah\right| \le \epsilon |h|/2$ whenever $\left|h\right| \le \delta_1$

similarly
$\left|F(a+h)- F(a) - Bh\right| \le \epsilon |h|/2$ whenever $\left|h\right| \le \delta_2$

(I am using the Euclidean Norm on both spaces since all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional spaces)

Choose $\delta = \text{min}(\delta_1, \delta_2)$, then by triangle inequality we get

$\left|Ah - Bh\right| \le \epsilon|h|$ when $\left|h\right| < \delta$

this gives
$\left|A - B\right| \le \epsilon$ when $|h| < \delta$

Hence, the two linear maps are same and therefore derivative is unique.

Is this proof correct? Please tell if there are any mistakes in my proof.

Thank You.

Comment: I think the final step could be clarified a little by saying something like "$|A - B| \le \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. Thus $|A - B| = 0$, hence $A = B$. Hence the two maps are the same..."

Comment: Have you studied operator norms? Can you prove that $|Ah - Bh| < \epsilon|h| \implies |A - B| < \epsilon$? This can be proved without talking about operator norms at all.